# PostgreSQL transforming the entire column value in a table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have been trying to change all the values in a column. When I do it turns out to take my table and drop all the rows that match my criteria in the where clause.

Example

```
|_Month_|_Cost_|_Title_| 
|___2___|_15.99|_hello_|
|___2___|_32.87|_John__|
|___2___|_32.87|_Neat__|
|___3___|_32.87|_Kelps_|
|___4___|_32.87|_Gulp__|
|___5___|_32.87|_Tried_|
```

I run this Query

```
UPDATE tableName SET Month = 'FEB' WHERE Month = 2;
```

The Change:

```
|_Month_|_Cost_|_Title_| 
|__FEB__|_32.87|_Neat__|
|___3___|_32.87|_Kelps_|
|___4___|_32.87|_Gulp__|
|___5___|_32.87|_Tried_|
```

What I need:

```
|_Month_|_Cost_|_Title_| 
|__FEB__|_15.99|_hello_|
|__FEB__|_32.87|_John__|
|__FEB__|_32.87|_Neat__|
|___3___|_32.87|_Kelps_|
|___4___|_32.87|_Gulp__|
|___5___|_32.87|_Tried_|
```

Where am I going wrong?

I have also tried to get the date changed from a timestamp with

```
SELECT TO_DATE(payment_timestamp, 'Mon") payment_month 
from tablename;
```

but PostgreSQL doesn't recognize the TO_DATE()?? Can someone tell me why?

Comment: What data type is the `month` column?  And `to_date()` most certainly works. What datatype is the `payment_timestamp` column?

Comment: Month data type is varchar(3). payment_timestamp is timestamp without time zone.

Comment: If the UPDATE didn't update all rows, then you probably have some white space in the column. Try `WHERE trim(Month) = '2'`. But storing numbers in a `varchar` column is a **really**, really bad idea. You should change that to an `integer` column before you proceed.

Comment: Ah, I was reading wrong. Obviously `to_date()` doesn't work as it expects a `text` or `varchar` as the input, you are looking for `to_char()` to convert a timestamp to a `varchar`

Comment: To update all months try `UPDATE tablename SET month = (array['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'])[trim(month)::integer]`;